# Open a MariaDB .Sql dump file in windows

Tags: windows, mariadb, dump

I'm quite new to Database stuff and this looks like a dumb question, but I haven't found an answer online so here I go:

I have a 3Go .sql file, which is a dump from a MariaDB database. I'm on windows with restricted rights, got nothing but DBrowser and DBeaver (community version). I want to be able to see the data in this dump, like tables, columns, and actual entries.

What I've tried so far:

- Using the "import" option in DBrowser, and it said it worked but it shows me an empty DB and the .db file created is only 8ko.
- Using DBeaver, but it needs to connect to a DB, and I have nothing to connect to.
- Opening the file directly with DBeaver; I got an out of memory error.
- Import the file as script in DBeaver, same error.
- found some mysql commands online, but I'm on windows so I don't have those.
- found some info on a "restore db" option in DBeaver, but must be in the pro version because I don't have it.

I've managed to open the file in a text editor, it's full of stuff like this:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `XXX`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `XXX`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `XXX` (
  `config` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `task_config` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sys_id` char(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sys_id`),
  KEY `task_config` (`task_config`),
  KEY `config` (`config`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `XXX`
--

set autocommit=0;
INSERT INTO `XXX` VALUES ( YYY )
commit;
```

So it looks like a valid dump from me? like it delete everything then recreates the table and insert some data?

So, how could I be able to "open" that DB? My last guess is installing MariaDB.msi for windows, makes a connection to localhost and creates an empty database to then import the dump in it, and at least connect to said database with DBeaver; but it looks like a lot of step to just be able to visualize a dump correctly, and since I have restricted rights I would need to ask for authorization, so I wanna be sure it's the right way to do it before I go for it.

Comment: A dump is plain text (SQL code). You can view the code or load the dump. To view the code you need a tool that supports very large files. To load the dump you need a database server. Both requirements are fairly reasonable.

Comment: I could view the code with VSCode, but it's a big file so it's a bit low and sometimes crash; but I saw enough to know that I don't want to see it that way. I want a proper display with tables/columns/entries as I normal have with DBrowser when I open .db files. So looks like I'll go for database server, thx.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Install [MySQL Community Server 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/).

Install [MySQL Workbench 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) to create the DB.

Use MySQL CLI to import database:

`mysql --host="127.0.0.1" --port=3306 --user=[User] --password [Database] < database.sql`

Use Workbench to view data.

If you want to see data, I think [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) can do the work, never used to open such huge file.

Comment: thx for your answer. Quick question: Why should I use MySQL Community Server instead of MariaDB server? Is one of them better? My dump file says it is a MariaDB so I thougt I really needed MariaDB server and not another.

Comment: It is a matter of preference, I use MySQL for 17 years, MariaDB is compatible with MySQL. Your sample dump even has the conditional commands for MySQL.

Comment: @PércolesTiagoNapivoski  Note that while MariaDB and MySQL share same heraitge and codebase, they are nowadays different products and there are differencies between them. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/incompatibilities-and-feature-differences-between-mariadb-10-10-and-mysql-8/

Comment: I never used MariaDB, can't say if there is difference, but that sample code has parts like conditional commands from MySQL (`/*!40101...`), what makes me believe it will be compatible with MySQL. OP can indeed prefer MariaDB and import DB through CLI that same way.

Comment: One thing that could speed up database creation and population in HDD is disabling write-cache buffer flushing. Note that this requires secured power supply.

Comment: Isn't that overhead to install MySQL Workbench for creating the db?

Comment: He will also use to view data but, indeed, no need to install it only to create DB, CLI would be enough.